# Azure Table Storage - filter column does not exist

Tags: azure-table-storage

So the way entities in Azure Table Storage are structured is that they only have columns they have been given a value to.

e.g:
PartitionKey | RowKey | SomeData | SomeTimestamp
PartitionKey | RowKey | SomeData

*Second "row" does not have any data in "SomeTimestamp"*

How can I build a filter query that will include entities without the given column?
i.e: I want "$filter='SomeTimestamp gt yesterday'" to return both rows, not just the one with data in "Sometimestamp"

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build a filter query that will include entities without the
>   given column? i.e: I want "$filter='SomeTimestamp gt yesterday'" to
>   return both rows, not just the one with data in "Sometimestamp"

It is not possible with Azure Tables. Unlike relational database, Azure Tables are essentially key/value pair based store and fields which are null are not even stored. So in your case, 2nd entity will only have 3 attributes: `PartitionKey`, `RowKey`, and `SomeData`.

Comment: Alright, shucks.. I was afraid of this.
Thanks for the response